# Epsilon Delta definition of limit of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to use the epsilon delta definition of the limit to find and prove the limit, if it exists, for $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3y}{x^2+y^4}$$
as $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$
Finding limits along various paths $x=y=0, y=mx$, etc., leads me to believe $L=0$

My attempt: Let $\epsilon>0$. Assume that $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$. Since $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>0$ for all $x,y$, then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ or $x^2+y^2<\delta ^2$
So we assume $x^2+y^2<\delta ^2$, then we show $$\biggr | \frac{x^3y}{x^2+y^4}\biggr |<\epsilon$$
And so, \begin{align} |x|\cdot|y|\cfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^4}&<\epsilon \\ \implies \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^4} \leq 1 \\ \implies \sqrt{x^2}\cdot\sqrt{y^2}&<\epsilon \\  x^2+y^2 < \epsilon\\ \end{align}
with $x^2+y^2<\delta^2$ and $x^2+y^2<\epsilon$ I choose $\delta^2=\epsilon$ or $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$. Hence, if $$0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\sqrt{\epsilon} \\ \implies x^2+y^2<\epsilon$$
Then  \begin{align*} \biggr | \cfrac{x^3y}{x^2+y^4}\biggr |&<\epsilon \\ \cfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^4}|x|\cdot|y|&< \epsilon \\ |x| \cdot |y| &< \epsilon \\ (\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2 &< \epsilon \\ x^2+y^2<\epsilon\end{align*}
Which is true from our premise, so then the limit is 0.

Is my reasoning sound or am I only getting the right answer by coincidence?

Comment: Since, when $|y|\leqslant1$, you actually have $y^4\leqslant y^2$, you have$$\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^4}\color{red}\geqslant\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I used the fact that since $x^2\leq x^2+y^4$ then $x^2/x^2+y^4 \leq 1$, hence $|(x^3y)/(x^2+y^4)| \leq |x| \cdot |y|$. And I used $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, hence $|x|\cdot |y| \leq x^2+y^2$ and so $x^2+y^2<\epsilon$

Comment: Did you or did you not write that $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^4}\leqslant\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: Oh oops, I see that now